# browsing JACKRABBIT content visually?

Tags: java, apache, jackrabbit, jcr, jsr170

i want to remove my current content from my DataBase tables.

and take them to a Content Repository (JCR)

is there any wizard that lets browsing [Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/) content visually.

because working with jackrabbit and loosing time becouse of running simple commands is really boring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found Toromiro, but i don't know where is the node i created it with command.

[Toromiro](https://www.subshell.com/en/sophora/modules/toromiro/index.html)

Comment: the link get 404

Answer (score 3):

You can try [JCR Explorer](http://www.jcr-explorer.org/screenshots.html). The project had no releases since 2007, but I had used it to access Jackrabbit 1.x repositories without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any good graphical tools that work well with recent jackrabbit versions. However I find the standalone CLI client quite powerful as it allows you to perform all the simple commands easily and is scriptable as well.
If you use the standalone server of jackrabbit you can connect either via davex (recommended)

```
java -jar jackrabbit-standalone-2.2.7.jar  --cli http://localhost:8080/server
```

or via RMI

```
java -jar jackrabbit-standalone-2.2.7.jar  --cli rmi://localhost:1099/rmi
```

E.g. creating a new node is as simple as issuing a

```
addnode "test"
```

Browsing the repository is done with the unix commands: cd, ls and in addition lsprop to list the property values.

For all commands that are available in the client run

```
help
```

Answer (score 1):

For a standalone Jackrabbit, repository content can be browsed using any http-browser.
For example, if I have standalone JR running at port 8087:

```
http://localhost:8087/repository/default/
```

Here "default" is workspace name, to access any other workspace just replace it with workspace name.
Of course, it is read-only and without any cool features, but it is bundled and lets browsing repository content without installing any additional tools.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Jackrabbit Explorer](http://code.google.com/p/jackrabbitexplorer/) as it has a GWT interface that allows "tree" style browsing and it can also search using XPath. The only down side is it appears not to support versioned nodes (it can't open them)

Answer (score 1):

Jackrabbit repositories can be browsed with WEBDAV clients, I have used WINSCP and it works perfectly.

FileZilla also should work as it supports WEBDAV (I have not tested it).

For WINSCP, the protocol needs to be selected to 'WEBDAV' from the session dialog and the full URL to the repository can be given in the 'host' fields of the dialog and the credential, for me it connected fine and I could browse file, download, deleta nd upload.